# Better approach for using URL strings for API calls

Tags: java, android, kotlin, retrofit

We had a discussion with colleagues and we did not come to a consensus.
I would be grateful for the good arguments and for the real experience of use.

The question is:

What is the better approach for declaring URL path, for example in Android application with Retrofit?

1. Using static string constant from separate file for all path items in the URL.

```
    @GET("$VIDEOS/$PUBLIC/{$SLUG}")
    fun getVideos(@Path(SLUG) slug: String, @Query(LIMIT) limit: Int): List<Video>
```

2. Using regular string.

```
    @GET("videos/public/{slug}")
    fun getVideos(@Path("slug") slug: String, @Query("limit") limit: Int): List<Video>
```

Comment: for me using static constants from separate file is useless because all your services is always declared in one interface so all the paths are always in it and it's not usefull to duplicate this values in another class. when i want to change a path i directly know that i have to go to my interface declaring services and not another constants class. I know it's not a long explained argument but for me it's sufficient. Hope to help you

Comment: Better by what objective metric(s)? As currently phrased, this is not really answerable because what's better is typically a matter of opinion, or at least based on your specific environment and needs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the second approach, the code becomes more readable - this is a very important advantage.

With the first approach, the advantage is only that if some piece of the path changes, it can be changed in one place only. But it is dubious advantage, because the path rarely changes and its change does not take much time with the second option too.

Disadvantages for second approach:

- additional dependencies are created that need to be tracked and you can change something unwanted by mistake,
- you have to check what is in each constant to make sure that the path is correct.

**Therefore, the answer is option 2 (regular string) is better.**

Answer (score 0):

Constants can be really powerful if the initial string are used within different areas of the codebase, for instance if you have two different URL's with the same `$VIDEOS` path, as you can edit this all at once. However, creating constants just because they 'may' be used in different places can be a nightmare to maintain. For instance as above, two API's use the `$VIDEOS` path but only one changes.

However on the other side, there can be a benefit in use here, and that is with the `slug`, from your example, but edited.

```
private const val SLUG = "thing"

@GET("videos/public/{$SLUG}")
fun getVideos(@Path($SLUG) slug: String, @Query("limit") limit: Int): List<Video>
```

As this is used in the same API call, but within two areas. The main point is that you can move things into constants, but only if it makes sense. Try not to abstract away your whole API as when you do, changing and maintaining will be harder.

When in doubt, I also fall back to the examples within the library themselves. [Retrofit Docs](https://square.github.io/retrofit/) The examples here do not have any constants.